# Hibernate QUERY inconsistent with 0

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

When I try to search for a fild with a string that starts with 0, it sometimes searchs for it ignoring the 0 at the start,returning the right result,but when that doesnt happen,it returns an error saying unexpected token:the rest of the string after the zero and one or two numbers

```
public String findSingleResultString(String parameter, Object T, String valueParameter, String field) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getFactory();
    // Select T.password from FROM User T WHERE T.cpf = 10
    String sql = "Select T." + field + " FROM " + T.getClass().getSimpleName() + " T  where T." + parameter + " ="
            + valueParameter;
    String results = session.createQuery(sql).getSingleResult().toString(); 

    return results;
}
```

Quickly explaining:parameter is for what you want to compare,Object is the table,ValueParameter is the value of the parameter you want to compare,and field is what you want it to return

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to pass parameters to a query. Use query parameters. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Comment: This is a SQL Injection vulnerability. Using a prepared statement would be safer.